# Why hasn't Mozilla's Firefox Beta PPA updated yet?

Tags: firefox, ppa, updates

I've included `ppa:mozillateam/firefox-next` in my Software Sources, but even though Firefox 9 beta got released, my system still has Firefox 8! Why is this, and how do I get the latest?

Answer (score 2):

The "ppa:mozillateam/firefox-next" should soon have Firefox 9beta1, and hen its ready, you'll be prompted to update.

If you want to, download a beta directly from Mozilla.

Update: Firefox 9b1 has been published in the PPA on November 16.

Comment: -1 Per https://launchpad.net/~mozillateam/+archive/firefox-next/+packages, firefox 9.0~b1 is currently pending, not published, so people on this PPA will be on firefox 8. See http://i.imgur.com/7jI1g.png.

Comment: Indeed, I must have looked at lines just below the right ones.

Answer (score 0):

press ctrl alt t to open a terminal window and do the following commands.

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-mozilla-daily/ppa

then

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install firefox-trunk

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, the guys running the firefox-next PPA run into some problems getting it built, which I think is the case now. You can manually check the status of their builds at https://launchpad.net/~mozillateam/+archive/firefox-next/+packages. Eventually, they'll fix it (they always do), but until then, you could:

- Keep an older version.
- Download 9.0b from firefox.com.
- Add the ubuntu-mozilla-daily ppa.
- Use some other clever solution that I didn't think of.